# Impossible to get JSON from Service into angularJs Routing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I've got this service :

```
 monApp.service('serviceEtatConnexion', function ($http) {
    this.getEtatConnexion = function () {
     return $http.get('backend/backend.php?action=get_etat_connexion');
  };
});
```

The back end php return this value , when called directly :

```
{"statuslogin":1}
```

IN my angularjs routing, i wanna get this value test this value like that :

```
resolve:{
    "check":function($window,serviceEtatConnexion,$location){
        var u = serviceEtatConnexion.getEtatConnexion();

        console.log('u est egal a ' +u);
        console.log(u.$$state.statuslogin);
        alert(JSON.stringify(u, null, 4));
       /*   if( u!= '{"$$state":{"status":0}}' ){
             alert("ok");
        }else{
             alert("Vous devez vous identifier pour utiliser cette partie");
            $window.location.href ='http://liseo.lan/dev/login.phtml?mlog=&domain=stuff';   

        } */
    }
    }
```

There is absolutly no way to get the statuslogin json value, look all that i've tried. I always see "undefined" inside the console
I don't understand why.

For info this is my php function , that encode a json correctly :

```
function get_etat_connexion(){

session_start();

include_once( "../../../globprefs.php" );
include_once( "../../../manage_session.php" );

$http_form_vars = count( $_POST ) > 0 ? $_POST : 
                                    ( count($_GET) > 0 ? $_GET : array("") );


if(USER&PASSWORD){

     $reponse['statuslogin']=1;
        echo(json_encode($reponse));


}

else{
     $reponse['statuslogin']=0;
        echo(json_encode($reponse));
}
```

}

Even this doesn't work and return undefined:

var statuslogin = $http.get('backend/backend.php?action=get_etat_connexion');
console.log('statuslogin est egal a ' +statuslogin);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http` service return promises which means that just calling the function will not return anything since the promise has yet to be resolved. Take a look at the following snippet

```
resolve:{
    "check":function($window,serviceEtatConnexion,$location, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        serviceEtatConnexion.getEtatConnexion()
            .then(function(result) {
                if (result.statusLogin === 1) {
                    // Everything is okay, resolve the promise with the result
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong, not logged in. Reject the promise
                    deferred.reject(result);
                }
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Then you can add whatever code to handle your error within the `if` statement. A common convention is to listen for the `$stateChangeError` event and handle redirects etc within that listener.

Comment: Yes finally it's not working when the person is not logged, i'm trying your solution

Comment: Its ok working finally , thank you a lot, just changed to  if (result.data.statuslogin === 1)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because you are assigning the variable `u` to the promise created by the `$http` service (which eventually get's resolved). What you really want is to wait until that promise is resolved and set the variable `u` to be assigned to the response returned by the promise's success callback. To fix

Change:

```
var u = serviceEtatConnexion.getEtatConnexion();
```

To:

```
var u = null;
serviceEtatConnexion.getEtatConnexion()
    .then(function(response){
        u = response.data;
    });
```

Now `u` should be equal to `{"statuslogin":1}`.